# How to find the kth minimum element from a Double linked list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I need to implement a function which can be find the kth minimum from doubly linked list.

I searched on internet and come to know about this :

- quickSelect logic and k-th order statistic algorithm would be effective for array or vector but here i am using linked list where I do not have any size of linked list so its hard to divide them in 5 elements part.

My function testcase is looks like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    // create linked list with 1000 elements
    int kthMinimum = findKthMin(LinkedList, i);
    // validate kthMinimum answer.
}
```

Here linkedlist can be in anyorder, we have to assume randomized only.

Any idea or suggestion to find kth minimum from doubly linked list in efficient time?

Thanks

Comment: Is list modification allowed?

Comment: @kraskevich yes its allowed

Comment: Don't forget that you can count the elements of the list and copy them into an array to perform quickselect. If you want to use median-of-medians, you can do so with linked lists directly, counting as you go.

Comment: @dfeuer how can i use median of medians algo with linked list direclty? any clue or hint?

Answer (score 2):

### Algorithm

You can maintain a heap of size `k` by doing the following:

1. Fill the array with the `k` first elements of the list.
2. Heapify the array (using a MaxHeap)
3. Process the remaining elements of the list:

   - If top of the heap (the max) is greater than the current element in the list *e*, replace it with *e* (and maintain the heap invariant)
   - If the element is greater, just ignore it and carry on

At the end of the algorithm, the k-th smallest element will be at the top of the heap.

### Complexity

Accumulate the first k elements + heapify the array: *O(k)*
Process the remaining part of the list *O((n-k)ln(k))*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It will give better performance then QuickSelect and Medians of Medians Algorithm?

Comment: @sam_k It's not better than Medians of Medians asymptotically. QuickSelect will perform better on average but has a quadratic worst case (here it's linearithmic). Though I feel you could tweak the algorithm of this answer to use a [soft heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_heap) to reach a linear time

Answer (score 0):

If the list is doubly-linked, you can run the QuickSort algorithm on it. On my experience QuickSort is the fastest sorting algorithm (measured generating random lists, and pitting it against HeapSort and MergeSort). After that, simply walk the list k-positions to get your k-th smallest element.

QuickSort average time is `O(n*log(n))`, walking the list will be `O(k)`, which in its worst case is `O(n)`. So, total time is `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: If walking the list will be o(k) then it would be O(k*n*long(n))

Comment: No, it would be O(k + n log(n)), which translates to O(n log (n)), as per the definition of Big O notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum). And yes, I think it would be ok to walk the list :)